# LDAP Date to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to parse the pwdLastSet value from NSTask response when I do an ldapsearch. I've successfully extracted the value (129875475241190194) and I am trying to convert it to an NSDate Object.

Reference: http://www.chrisnowell.com/information_security_tools/date_converter/Windows_active_directory_date_converter.asp

I tried to extract the Javascript code from the page above and convert it but I am getting a different date.

```
        int iYearsFrom1601to1970 = 1970 - 1601;
        int iDaysFrom1601to1970 = iYearsFrom1601to1970 * 365;
        iDaysFrom1601to1970 += (int)(iYearsFrom1601to1970 / 4); // leap years
        iDaysFrom1601to1970 -= 3; // non-leap centuries (1700,1800,1900).  2000 is a leap century
        float iSecondsFrom1601to1970 = iDaysFrom1601to1970 * 24 * 60 * 60;

        int iTotalSecondsSince1601 = (int)(129875475241190194 / 10000000);

        float iTotalSecondsSince1970 = iTotalSecondsSince1601 - iSecondsFrom1601to1970;

        NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:iTotalSecondsSince1970];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the date are you getting for your result?  And what is the date are expecting?

Comment: Expected: 
Mon, 23 Jul 2012 20:05:24 GMT
Getting:
2009-04-22 19:28:22 +0000

Comment: Also this is reason you don't want to calculate seconds since 1601: ...in the last millennium, 1600 and 2000 were leap years, but 1700, 1800 and 1900 were not. Excerpt from Wikipedia [Gregorian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar).  And there is the whole thing about dropping 10 days to sync with the Romans. A huge mess.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
NSDateComponents *base = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[base setDay:1];
[base setMonth:1];
[base setYear:1601];
[base setEra:1]; // AD

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDate *baseDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:base];
[base release];
[gregorian release];

NSTimeInterval timestamp = 129875475241190194.0 / 10000000.0;

NSDate *finalDate = [baseDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:timestamp];
```

This gives me a `finalDate` of `2012-07-24 03:58:22 +0000`.

Since the timestamp is a time interval since Jan 1, 1601 at 00:00 UTC, you can use the `-dateByAddingTimeInterval:` method on `NSDate` to add the timestamp to the base date to get the final `NSDate`.

Once you've done that, you can run it through an `NSDateFormatter` to format it for display.

Comment: This answer is not correct because it 's not taking into account leap years.

Comment: @BlackFrog um... `NSDate` has no concept of leap years. Those are only relevant when you're wanting to build a human-readable date. I'd also like to point out that your answer is fundamentally equivalent to mine. Go watch session 244 from this year's WWDC...

Comment: so you are telling me if I have the following date of Feb. 28, 2012 at 10:30 pm (UTC) and I add 6 hours to it the result would be March 1, 2012 at 4:30 am (UTC)?  Not Feb. 29, 2012 because this year is a leap year?

Comment: @BlackFrog it would be six hours after 2/28/2012 @22:30UTC.  Whether that's the 29th or the 1st depends on the `NSCalendar` used.  An `NSDate` is just an offset in time from the reference date. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: you are correct.  NSDate just keeps a reference to an offset in time.  But no matter how we get the calculate the answer we should arrive at the same answer.  I just think the your calculation is not taking into account leap years.

Comment: @BlackFrog "not taking into account leap years" doesn't make sense. An `NSDate` is an offset in time, irrespective of any calendaring system.  How could an offset have any notion of what a leap year is? Those are relative to a calendar.  I take one offset in time (that happens to correspond to 1/1/1601) and add another offset to it, to arrive at a different offset in time.  It's only when I want to convert that offset into a human-readable form that leap anythings come into play, and that's all handled by `NSCalendar`.

Comment: Thanks Dave and blackfrog :):)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the, well, daring conversion between the basetimes is correct: actually looking at the warnings, instead of casting them away, might actually help:

```
int main(void)
{
    int iTotalSecondsSince1601 = (129875475241190194 / 10000000);
    return 0;
}

stieber@gatekeeper:~$ clang++ Test.cpp
Test.cpp:4:8: warning: implicit conversion from 'long' to 'int' changes value from 12987547524 to 102645636
....
```

That should account for a good deal of the difference...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSTimeInterval value = 129875475241190194;
// instead of trying to compute seconds between 1601 and 1970
const NSTimeInterval EPOCH = 11644473600;
const NSTimeInterval NANO = 10000000;

NSTimeInterval seconds = value / NANO - EPOCH;
NSDate *answer = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];
```

Also this is reason you don't want to calculate seconds since 1601: ...in the last millennium, 1600 and 2000 were leap years, but 1700, 1800 and 1900 were not. Excerpt from Wikipedia on [Gregorian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar).

The value for EPOCH is explained on [Convert Active Directory "LastLogon:" time to (UNIX) readable time](http://meinit.nl/convert-active-directory-lastlogon-time-to-unix-readable-time)
.

*Note:* The information about **accountExpires** which starts from 12-31-1601 (11644473600). The values **lastLogon** and **lastLogonTimeStamp** however use 01-01-1601 as the date to calculate this value (11676009600).